# Oracleクライアントの32bitと64bitの共存について

Tags: oracle

現在、Windows Server2012で業務アプリケーション（VB.NETで作成）を稼働させております。
その、開発環境としてWindows10(x64)のクライアントにOracle 12cの64bit版（データベースおよびクライアント)をインストールし、VisualStudio2015のVB.NETでアプリケーションの保守および新規アプリケーションの開発（クライアント環境において動作確認を行う）を行っております。

今回、上記クライアントに32bit版のOracleクライアントで実行されるアプリケーションを導入することになりました。
oracleクライアントの64bit版と32bit版との共存は可能でしょうか。
もし、可能であれば、その方法をご教授願えないでしょうか。

Answer (score 1):

マニュアルに記載されてますが、My Oracle Supportでノート1243374.1および781432.1を参照してください。

[Oracle Database Clientのインストール前の作業](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E57425_01/121/NTCLI/pre_install.htm#CIHIAGFG)

> 2.6.3 64ビット・プラットフォーム用の独立した32ビット・クライアント・ソフトウェア
>
> Oracle Database 11gリリース2(11.2)以降では、64ビット・クライアント・ソフトウェアに32ビット・クライアント・バイナリは含まれません。64ビット・プラットフォーム上で32ビット・クライアント・バイナリが必要な場合は、それぞれの32ビット・クライアント・ソフトウェアから、32ビット・バイナリをインストールできます。
>
> 32ビット・クライアントのバイナリを64ビット・プラットフォームにインストールする際、インストーラにより既存の32ビット・ソフトウェアの確認が行われます。
>
> 関連項目:
>   32ビットと64ビットのOracle Database Clientソフトウェアの両方を同じシステムにインストールする場合は、My Oracle Supportで次のノート1243374.1および781432.1を参照してください。
>
> https://support.oracle.com/CSP/main/article?cmd=show&type=NOT&id=1243374.1
>   https://support.oracle.com/CSP/main/article?cmd=show&type=NOT&id=781432.1

Answer (score 1):

できますよ。
Oracleのホームページのどっかにも書いてあると思うんですが、`Oracleベース・ディレクトリ`を分けてやることで実現できます。

ただ、32bit版のdownload pathとかなかなか見つからなかったような記憶がありますね...
また、登録されるassembly versionが32bitと64bitで異なってもまともに動かなかったような記憶があります。versionによっては32bit版が提供されてなかったりもします。
32bit版クライアントのversion指定が無く、かつ64bit版とversionを揃えたclientがあり、なおかつそのversionで新規に導入されるアプリケーションが動作するという前提ですが...

先に書いたようにOracleベースディレクトリ(インストールパスの`c:\app\`に続くdir名)を分けてやることで共存は実現できたと思います。

---

少し前の環境での備忘録ですが参考までに...
https://www21.atwiki.jp/ohden/pages/726.html